# Is there an instrument to measure/uniquely identify gadget's RF signal strength

Tags: rf, radio, interference, spectrum-analyzer, power-meter

I'm not a technical person. Apologies for not being able to express myself clearly.

I have a base station(blackbox audience response system bought from manufacturer) used during events that transmits 2.4GHZ RF signals across the halls. (E.g Huge Convention Halls)

I want to measure the signal strength from this gadget at different parts of the hall where it is placed in order to see which area has weak signal.

However, in public places, there may be other RF signals from unknown devices.

Are there instruments that I can use to measure/uniquely identify the power/signal strength of my base station?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a WiFi signal? If not, what is it?

Comment: @SteveG it's not a WiFi signal. It's a USB powered base station that is used in an audience response system.  Think voting devices. So the base station sends a RF signal to voting keypads and voting keypads sends RF signals back to the base station with user inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You have already identified that the crucial part of this instrument is to only measure the signal strength of the voting system base station. If that unit used a standard protocol such as WiFi there are a number of instruments available that can do exactly that. Even an Android phone can run a WiFi Analyser app to give you an uncalibrated measurement of signal strength. But it sounds like your voting system uses a non-standard protocol. To be able to measure its signal strength you need to know:

- the frequencies or channels in use
- the modulation scheme
- the format of the data packets so that you can decode the packet and identify that it is from the voting system base station.

The only people who will know all of those things are the manufacturers of the voting system. It is possible that they already have a signal strength meter for use with their system. I would contact them.

Answer (score 0):

An RF power meter can be used to measure the power level of a specific RF signal.  That signal will be the transmit signal of the RF channel.

If multiple RF devices use the same channel/s (like wifi), then you may need a different device to decode the RF signal identifier for each device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply DIYser. May I know what that device to decode RF signal identifier is called?

Comment: It will have to be a device that is compatible with the RF standard that the RF devices conform to.  If the radios use a custom/proprietary system, then you will have to find a device that is compatible with that system.  In the case of a standard system (like wifi) you could use portable pc/arduino software to scan for RF devices, decode their mac or ip addresses, compute their RF power levels,change your position to get sufficient information to compute (triangulate) on the position of the RF device that you want to locate.  I can't provide you with a specific device name, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use a field strength meter to measure continuous or near continuous transmissions.

Probably doesn't suit your scenario as you need to uniquely identify the correct transmission, and it may be a very short transmission. It might also not be transmitted on a single frequency.

A radio receiver can serve as a field strength meter. Some (single frequency) receiver chips have a received signal strength indicator (RSSI)

A spectrum analyser is the ultimate tool to, well, to analyse a spectrum of frequencies. Unfortunately it scans from one frequency to another and can miss very short transmissions. The handsets have very short transmissions to prolong battery life. The "base station" may or not transmit at all.

So, we don't really have enough information to give a fool proof answer.

You could get a qualitative answer by reducing transmitter power. Say by half, and wander about the room to see if it still works everywhere.

You can reduce the signal by half by altering the antenna. Or cutting the feed to the antenna and inserting 3 resistors (Pi attenuator). Or maybe software configuration somehow.

Ask a radio ham for help.

Regards
Ian Mccrum

__